# Customizing routes for nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have the following resources:

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :store do
    resources :candy
  end
end
```

As you know, this generates routes for 6 HTTP Actions, including the nested `store/store_id/candy/...` routes. This is fine with me, however I want only use GET and POST instead of PATH/PUT and DELETE

`POST store/destroy/:id` and `POST store/update/:id` would be the ideal behavior for me.

First of all, is this breaking convention and if not, is there an easy way to generate such routes?

Comment: Please take a look at [the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default). If `stores` shouldn't be a collection then use `resource :store` (notice `resource` is singular). You can control which methods are supported via `only:` and `except:` arguments. For example `resources :candies, only: [:show, :create]` will route `GET /candies/:id` and `POST /candies` to `CandiesController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you are not wanting to use the PATH/PUT and DELETE methods? By not using these methods you are going against Rail's RESTful routing conventions but it is possible to create the routes you are looking for:

```
resource :store, except: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy, :show] do
  resources :candy
end
post '/store/destroy/:id', to: 'store#destroy', as: :destory_store
post '/store/update/:id', to: 'store#update', as: :update_store
```

This way should give you the nested candy routes you want then the following 2 routes would give you the post requests you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll stick to the convention then. The only reason I ask is because Twitter (which was originally built on Rails) has only GET and POST requests for both creation and destruction of statuses (Tweets) so I thought more people would be used to that